# Excel Filter and join between multiple tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm reasonable user of Excel (definitely not very skilled though) - I'm using Excel 2013.

I'd like some assistance on how to achieve what I need on table controls. I've created three tables.

- table 1 (Spend) has three columns (values,category,subcategory) => values = 2, 10, 3, 12.
- table 2 (Category) has one column (category) => Groceries, train fare, lunch, rent.
- table 3 (Subcategory) has one column (subcategory) => market stall, college, canteen, rent.

What I'd like to do is to have drop down or autocompletion entries to be available in table 1. I'd like to choose the cateogries in table 1 Category column, but these choices need to be sourced from table 2 (Category), likewise the same should apply for table 1 Subcategory column.

Could someone please advise me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is some sort of tiered data-validation, like -

[click for larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASAGV.png)
[image]

So in the Ribbon you'll have data - data validation. You can set lists that are available based on conditions. For instance, D2 is restricted to the list in A6:A8 by using "List" with that as the sort.

Now, it's a little bit trickier for E2, but basically it picks what's available from the list B10:B15, based on what has been chosen in D2. It's two nested `if` statements -

```
=IF(D2=A6,B10:B11,IF(D2=A7,B12:B13,B14:B15)
```

All you'd need to do is apply it to your ranges with the correct references and you're done, no VBA required.